# After installing Debian on USB stick, stick does not boot on MacBook

Tags: linux, boot, usb, debian, grub

My goal is to install Debian to be bootable from a usb stick on a MacBook with two usb ports.  To do so I booted from Debian Live flash on the first usb port. Next I used to Debian installer to install Debian on the second USB port. Installation completed with a message that Debian was successfully  installed. Yet Debian does not boot from the usb where it was installed by installer.

```
Live system partitions:
Device: /dev/sdc1,  Boot: *, Size: 3.2G,  Id:0, Type: Empty  
Device: /dev/sdc2,  Boot:  , Size: 5M,  Id:ef, Type: EFI (FAT-12/16/32)

Partitions of the usb where installer installed Debian:
Device: /dev/sdd1,  Boot:  , Size: 99M,  Id:c, Type: W95 FAT32 (LBA)  
Device: /dev/sdd2,  Boot: , Size: 14.5G,  Id:83, Type: Linux
```

After booting MacBook from the Debian Live USB stick, I try to reinstall bootloader on the second USB stick with:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdd2 /mnt

sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys

sudo chroot /mnt

grub-install /dev/sdd
update-grub
```

And `grub-install /dev/sdd` returns:

```
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install error: cannot find EFI directory
```

Any ideas how to make it boot?

**Update**

As suggested by ChanganAuto, I have added `sudo mount /dev/sdd1 /mnt/boot/efi`. Now it looks like `grub-install` works:

```
user@debian:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdd1 /mnt/boot/efi
user@debian:~$ sudo chroot /mnt
root@debian:/# grub-install /dev/sdd
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: warning: EFI variables are not supported on this system..
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

Not sure about `update-grub`, though:

```
root@debian:/# update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-18-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-18-amd64
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdb1.  Check your device.map.
```

Add yet usb still does not boot.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be working towards is a live, bootable Debian image with [*persistence*](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/03/create-persistent-storage-live-usb-with.html). Essentially, it is a full Linux installation on USB.

Since you already made a bootable Debian USB drive, you've learned most of what is needed. However, to enable persistence, [an additional partition must be created](https://gist.github.com/chrisdiana/282b416986c4597d71812cba467bc1fd). A summary from that site:

1. Download the Debian ISO.
2. Modify the ISO to use persistence.
3. Put it on USB and boot from it.
4. *Create and format an additional partition* for persistence.
5. Create a mount point.

Note that additional drivers, e.g., audio and Bluetooth, may need to be installed *after* creating the persistent instance.

Comment: How to modify the  Debian Live ISO to use persistence?

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/chrisdiana/282b416986c4597d71812cba467bc1fd .It's a bit long.

Comment: Trying to make persistent bootable Debian image was the first thing I started with before installing it on usb. Unfortunately command:
`LANG=C sed 's/splash quiet/persistence /;s/quiet splash/persistence /' \
    </debian-live-10.0.0-amd64-mate.iso \
    >/debian-live-10.0.0-amd64-mate-persist.iso
`
fails on MacOS Unix, and I currently have no Linux machine where it may work.

Comment: Although a "live with persistence" is a viable solution it might not be the best. So, I disagree with the premise of this answer and I suggest you were on the right track but used the wrong method - it's a UEFI system (and it can't work any other way because Apple) so you must  mount the ESP (it seems to have been correctly created - `sdd1` - and then (re)install Grub):  https://wiki.debian.org/GrubEFIReinstall (ignore the parts about LUKS, of course) I suspect you need only to add `mount /dev/sdd1 /mnt/boot/efi` and #4 (maybe).

Comment: Please see my updated question.